# sequelize left join returning data for associated table too

Tags: mysql, node.js, join, sequelize.js, left-join

I have two table hence models and association defined them as follow.

```
assigned_jobs
------------------------
id | job_id | emp_id 
1  |    1   | 5
2  |    2   | 6
3  |    3   | 3
4  |    4   | 2

matched_technicians
------------------------
id | job_id | emp_id 
1  |    1   | 5
2  |    1   | 6
3  |    3   | 3
4  |    3   | 2
5  |    4   | 5
6  |    4   | 6
7  |    3   | 3
8  |    3   | 2
8  |    5   | 2
```

So there is multiple jobs with same id in `matched_technicians` but only record for a `job_id` in `assigned_job`

```
AssignedJob.hasMany(models.MatchedTechnicians, { sourceKey: 'job_id', foreignKey: 'job_id' })
MatchedTechnicians.hasOne(models.AssignedJob, { sourceKey: 'job_id', foreignKey: 'job_id' })
```

I want to get all those records from `matched_technicians` which doesn't have any record for that `job_id` in `assigned_jobs`.

I am trying something below.

```
let alreadyMatchedJobs = await MatchedTechnician.findAll({
    include: {
      model: AssignedJob,
      required: false,
      attributes: ['job_id'],
    },
    group: ['job_id'],
    attributes: ['job_id', 'id'],
  });
```

Here I am left joining `matched_technicians` with `assigned_jobs` and getting result with `GROUP BY job_id`

It is generating following query.

```
SELECT `MatchedTechnician`.`job_id`, `MatchedTechnician`.`id`, `AssignedJob`.`id` AS `AssignedJob.id`, `AssignedJob`.`job_id` AS `AssignedJob.job_id`
FROM `matched_technicians` AS `MatchedTechnician`
LEFT OUTER
JOIN `assigned_jobs` AS `AssignedJob` ON `MatchedTechnician`.`job_id` 
= `AssignedJob`.`job_id`
GROUP BY `job_id`;
```

Giving result as below.

```
[
    {
        "job_id": 1,
        "id": 144,
        "AssignedJob": {
            "job_id": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "job_id": 2,
        "id": 145,
        "AssignedJob": {
            "job_id": 2
        }
    },
    {
        "job_id": 3,
        "id": 3,
        "AssignedJob": {
            "job_id": 3
        }
    },
    {
        "job_id": 4,
        "id": 2,
        "AssignedJob": {
            "job_id": 4
        }
    },
    {
        "job_id": 5,
        "id": 151,
        "AssignedJob": null
    }
]
```

Here I don't understand why it's giving records which have `job_id` in both tables. 
I want here only record with `job_id, 5`.

Comment: @Strawberry It really doesn't make any sense to me. What else should I include? I made my question clear enough. It has everything one can easily digest the question.

Comment: Yous should read both parts of @strawberry comment,

Comment: @P.Salmon    She edited her statement . She included first part later. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear documentation for excluding `NULL` valued rows  when doing left join.
I had to do something like below.

```
let alreadyMatchedJobs = await MatchedTechnician.findAll({
    where: {
      '$AssignedJob.job_id$': {
        [Op.eq]: null,
      },
    },
    include: {
      model: AssignedJob,
      required: false,
    },
    group: ['job_id'],
    attributes: ['job_id', 'id'],
  });
```